# Uniform convergence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}$ if $|x| > c$ for all $c>0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

**Problem** : Prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}$ : converges uniformly if $|x| > c$ for all $c>0$

I'm stuck.. Can anybody provide me a hint to solve this..?

**My attempt** : Choose d s.t. $|x| > d$ and

Comment: [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3456503/does-sum-n-0-infty-fracx21x2n-converge-uniformly-on-infty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f_n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^2\dfrac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}$$
is a geometric series. And it will converge if $\dfrac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}<1\implies x\neq0$.

For all $x\neq0$, using the formula for geometric series, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}=1+x^2,x\neq0$, therefore $f_n(x)$ converges poinwise to $f$ when $x\neq0$. Use the definition of uniform convergence in terms of suprema:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}|f(x)-f_m(x)|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|  1+x^2-x^2 \frac{1-(1+x^2)^{-(m+1)}}{1-(1+x^2)^{-1}}\right|=0=\lim\sup_{x\neq0}|f(x)-f_m(x)|$$

Answer (score 2):

Weiestraß' $M$-test: Use that for $x$ with $|x|>c$ we have 
$$\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}\leq \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\frac{1}{(1+c^2)^{n-1}}\leq \frac{1}{(1+c^2)^{n-1}}.$$